# How to send xhr.responseXML object from background.html to contentscript.js

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-extension, xss

I want to send the object returned by the xhr.responseXML statement from the background.html file to the contentscript.js file in my google chrome extension so that I will be able to access/mosify that object in the content script.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In background page:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"});
});
```

in content script:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("Received data:", request);
});
```

It is called message passing, you can read more about it [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/messaging.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answwer. Will I be able to send a javascript variable that contains access to XML DOM through this mechanism?

Comment: @Nitish You can send anything that could be serialized to json. So if you received XML document you can send it as a string (sending DOM object would be problematic as it is very complex and has circular references which would make json serialization fail)